# 'java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type' - while inserting into the database

Tags: java, spring, oracle11g, mybatis

I am trying to insert a row into the database through an application build on spring framework and uses mybatis for database handling. My table looks like this:

```
create table EPAY_OWNER.EPAY_CUSTOMERS
(
  customer_id                NUMBER(19) not null,
  customer_nbr               VARCHAR2(20),
  customer_first_name        VARCHAR2(50),
  customer_last_name         VARCHAR2(50),
  customer_address_1         VARCHAR2(100),
  customer_address_2         VARCHAR2(100),
  customer_state_or_province VARCHAR2(2),
  customer_postal_code       VARCHAR2(9),
  customer_phone             VARCHAR2(15),
  customer_fax               VARCHAR2(15),
  customer_email             VARCHAR2(100),
  customer_city              VARCHAR2(50),
  customer_country           VARCHAR2(25),
  created_by_userid          VARCHAR2(9),
  created_date               TIMESTAMP(6),
  epay_merchant_id           NUMBER(19)
)
```

CUSTOMER_ID is the primary key and EPAY_MERCHANT_ID is a foreign key. All the fields are nullable except the primary key.
And my mybatis mapper xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >

<mapper namespace="com.ge.epay.web.dao.EpayCustomerDAO">

    <!-- Inserting a new customer -->
    <insert id="insertCustomer" parameterType="com.ge.epay.web.models.EpayCustomerModel">
        <selectKey keyProperty="customerId" order="BEFORE" resultType="java.lang.Long">
            SELECT EPAY_OWNER.EPAY_CUSTOMER_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
        </selectKey>
        INSERT INTO EPAY_OWNER.EPAY_CUSTOMERS
            (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NBR, CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME, CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_1, CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_2,
            CUSTOMER_STATE_OR_PROVINCE, CUSTOMER_POSTAL_CODE, CUSTOMER_PHONE, CUSTOMER_FAX, CUSTOMER_EMAIL, CUSTOMER_CITY,
            CUSTOMER_COUNTRY, CREATED_BY_USERID, CREATED_DATE, EPAY_MERCHANT_ID)
        VALUES
            (#{customerId}, #{customerNbr}, #{firstName}, #{lastName}, #{custAddr1}, #{custAddr2}, #{custState}, #{custZip},
            #{custPhone}, #{custFax}, #{custEmail}, #{custCity}, #{custCountry}, #{createdBy}, SYSTIMESTAMP, #{merchantId})
    </insert>
</mapper>
```

And the model EpayCustomerModel is:

```
    private long customerId;
    private String customerNbr;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String custAddr1;
    private String custAddr2;
    private String custCity;
    private String custState;
    private String custCountry;
    private String custZip;
    private String custPhone;
    private String custFax;
    private String custEmail;
    private String createdBy;
    private String createdDate;
    private int merchantId;
```

And the value that I am trying to insert is:

```
EpayCustomerModel [customerId=0, customerNbr=10254, firstName=Test, lastName=Customer, custAddr1=Address 1, custAddr2=Address 2, custCity=Some, custState=FL, custCountry=null, custZip=45986, custPhone=null, custFax=null, custEmail=null.null@ge.com, createdBy=990027140, createdDate=null, merchantId=7]
```

It is throwing invalid column type exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getInternalType(OracleStatement.java:3433)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setNullCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4261)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setNull(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4250)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setNull(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:157)
at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.setParameter(BaseTypeHandler.java:15)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.parameter.DefaultParameterHandler.setParameters(DefaultParameterHandler.java:73)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.parameterize(PreparedStatementHandler.java:61)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.parameterize(RoutingStatementHandler.java:43)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(SimpleExecutor.java:56)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:28)
```

Am I doing something wrong? I am totally stuck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you've only have not null on customer_id column and stacktrace complains on setNull(). Do you have EPAY_OWNER.EPAY_CUSTOMER_SEQ sequence?

Comment: createdDate being String is strange, and inserted it should not be. Make it a Date.

Comment: Will that make a difference @JoopEggen? As I am not using that field while inserting. I have directly inserted SYSTIMESTAMP. Still let me give it a try.

Comment: I have a EPAY_OWNER.EPAY_CUSTOMER_SEQ @user1455836. Strange thing is the value of the sequence is incremented everytime I run the program but the row is not inserted. Means it is picking up the next value from the sequence but not able to insert the data.

Comment: Right, should not. Still would try without CREATED_DATE/SYSTIMESTAMP in the INSERT. Though I think I am wrong, and your search seems more promising: the sequence.

Comment: I changed the type of createdDate to Calendar. Still got the same error. tried with out systimestamp using #{createdDate} Still the same error.

Comment: I think you have to use keyProperty and/or keyColumn attributes within <insert> tag.